# Changing request header before forward proxy in Apache

Tags: apache2, mod-proxy, request-headers

I have used "forward proxy" in Apache. I want to change part of request header before passing the request. for example i want to change host param in header.
i have used this part of config in httpd.conf but it doesn't change header before passing the request.

```
Listen 7654
<VirtualHost *:7654>
    RequestHeader set Host "test.com"
    ProxyRequests On
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 6):

I've found that adding `ProxyPreserveHost On` to the `VirtualHost` config enables rewriting of the `Host:` header as intended.

Answer (score 0):

have you install mod_headers on apache ?

if you have no install then try command "a2enmod headers" (without qoute) and restart apache.